# Solana, how to send a NFT (spl token) to another wallet using javascript/wallets

Tags: token, blockchain, solana, nft

I'm trying to figure out how to send an NFT and display it on a website. Ideally the NFT can be dropped on the account linked to the website and therefore "belongs" to the website at least for a while, this is important for my project because I need to be able to burn the nft or send it back to the user. Actually im using @project-serum/anchor and @solana/web3.js but I can't even get a transfer between the user's wallet and another wallet.

I've spent all day trying to figure out how to do it but I can't get a result. Ideally I would have a button that opens the wallet and shows the different NFT that can be deposited, the user chooses one that is sent to the wallet linked to the site.

I thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
// This transaction is sending the tokens
var transaction = new web3.Transaction().add(
  splToken.Token.createTransferInstruction(
    splToken.TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
    fromTokenAccount.address,
    toTokenAccount.address,
    fromWallet.publicKey,
    [],
    1000000, // This is transferring 1 token, not 1000000 tokens
  ),
);

var signature = await web3.sendAndConfirmTransaction(
  connection,
  transaction,
  [fromWallet],
  {commitment: 'confirmed'},
);

console.log("SIGNATURE: ", signature);
let tokenBalance = await toTokenAccount.amount;
console.log("token balance: ", tokenBalance);
```